Commas around parenthetical phrase
Does the following phrase work with and without commas?

He has provided valuable insights, through his work on several projects in the field, to the rest of the team.


With or without commas, this sentence remains  awkward. A solution to do away with the awkwardness is using an other position for the adverbial.

Through his work on several projects in the field, he has provided valuable insights to the rest of the team.
He has provided valuable insights  to the rest of the team through his work on several projects in the field.

